# SignalR multiple chat rooms

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net, signalr

Buenas tengo una pregunta cuando envio a todos los usuarios me deja anda bien, pero cuando lo limito a solo los usuarios que esten en determinados grupos pasandole el Id de la sala directamente no me llegue nada del Hub directamente, la verdad que no se que puede ser que estoy haciendo mal.

Este en el BackEnd en .Net

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendMessage([FromBody] MessagesForCreationDto message)
    {

        if (message == null)
        {
            
                _logger.LogError("Message object sent from client is null.");
                return BadRequest("Message object is null");
        }

        message.Room = Convert.ToString(message.FK_ChatRoomID);


        var messages = _mapper.Map<Messages>(message);

        _repository.Messages.Create(messages);

        _repository.Messages.SaveAsync();

        string not = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

         //_hubContext.Clients.Group(message.Room).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", not);

        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", not);

        return Ok();
    }

y asi es como esta puesto en Angular

  export class ChatService extends DataService {
  public hubConnection: HubConnection;
  messageReceived: EventEmitter<Messages> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, '/chatrooms');

    console.log('Inicio el servicio signal con cambio');

    const builder = new HubConnectionBuilder();
    this.hubConnection = builder.withUrl('https://localhost:5001/chat').build();

    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (mensaje) => {
      const not: Messages = JSON.parse(mensaje);
      this.messageReceived.emit(not);

      console.log(mensaje);
    });
    this.hubConnection.start();
  }
}
```

asi es como tengo el Ts de donde hago un push al Array Messages para añadirle nuevos mensajes.

```
  msj: Messages[] = [];

  getById() {
    this.handler = this.chatService.getById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.chat = data;
      this.msj.push(...this.chat.messages);
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que el código se comparte como texto (no te van a responder con imágenes para ponerte a transcribir).

Comment: Y del lado del cliente (receiver) como estas declarando el codigo

Comment: ahi subi como lo tengo, no se si es suficiente.